# How to fix spaces when using website requests in py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command as always but i cannot use them with a space in between. This is my code at the moment.

```
@client.command()
async def cautionsign(ctx, msg):
  embed = discord.Embed(title="Here's your caution sign!")
  embed.set_image(url=f"https://api.popcat.xyz/caution?text={msg}")
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

For ex if i use

> !cautionsign
> test

it will show a cautionsign with test on it but if i use

> !cautionsign test
> test

it will just show test.

If anyone can help me i'd appreciate it :)

Comment: Use the `replace` method, doing the following your request will work as expected.
`msg.replace(' ', "%20")`.

Comment: Yeah that also works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the `urllib.parse.quote` to properly escape url components.  For example...

```
from urllib.parse import quote
embed.set_image(url=f"https://api.popcat.xyz/caution?text={quote(msg)}")
```

Comment: Thank you I tried to do the same thing but i used "{urllib.parse.quote(msg)}" instead of "{quote(msg)}"